# Checkbox in custom UITableViewCell deselects on row select

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, uitableview

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` which works as expected.
Except for one ( important ) detail.

My cell ( loaded from Nib ) contains a `UIButton` ( set to custom ).
That button acts like a checkbox.
Most of the time that checkbox is selected ( = checked )
using custom images:

```
[self.checkboxButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_off"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.checkboxButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_on"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

**The problem is:**
When I select my row, the checkbox(button) automatically deselects.
I've been all over my code to see where this is coming from and
do not set the selected property on the checkbox anywhere but in 
my custom tableviewcell code.

**The interesting part is:**
when I set my `tableviewcell.selectionstyle` to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone` everything works as expected ( sans custom backgrond color ).
When I switch to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray` the checkbox is unselected automatically.

**Update**
When I overwrite `setSelected:animated:` my checkbox stays checked.

```
- (void) setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    // checkbox stays checked as expected
    NSLog(@"set select with anim");
    // when calling super setSelected:animated: checkbox gets unchecked
    // [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
}
```

Is there some mechanism I'm missing?
For example, do I have to overwrite `setSelected:`, `drawRect`, …
I've run out of ideas how to tackle this illusive bug.

Thanks.

Comment: did you call `reloadData` when selecting cell? if yes, that can be the reason of your problem.

Comment: I did a find and replace on `[[self tableView] reloadData];`in my tableviewcontroller and have a central method now to reload the tableview's data.  Once the table's data is in place, this method is not called again.  So thanks for your suggestion, but it doesn't seem to be the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you uncheck the checkbox in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: No, even with an empty method body, the issue still occurs.  

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        
    }